# Uploading zip file to sharepoint using REST is not saving the file contents

Tags: sharepoint

Uploading zip file to sharepoint using REST is not saving the file contents. The operation is sucessful. But when the file is downloaded from site to local machine, its failing to open the zip and showing 0 bytes

Comment: could you please add your code snippet and which REST endpoint are you using to upload content ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery

Creating the item (with the meta data) in the library and upload the file (binary) are two seperate actions you have to handle to complete the upload. I think you only add an item to the library and not uploading the binary data?